# Parameterised MDX query does not recognise parameters

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2012

I have an MDX Query in reporting services (built with query builder) which looks like this:

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Injury Illness Cases] } ON COLUMNS
, NON EMPTY { ([DimI Gender].[Gender Text].[Gender Text].ALLMEMBERS 
* [DimI State].[State Text].[State Text].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION 
PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DimIStateStateText, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( { [DimI Gender].[Gender Text].&[Female], [DimI Gender].[Gender Text].&[Male] } ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [US Census Final Injuries])) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR
, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

The problem is I used to have user-input, query-based parameter here (@DimIStateStateText) and the report used to run fine. I was, however, forced to changed it to free text parameter, and even when I type in the exact same value as it was shown before (e.g. Oklahoma) the reports doesn't return any data.

What is the cause of this? Can I provide the parameter without changing the whole query to dynamic string?